# Reverse Array Error

Tags: java, arrays

I keep getting same error message when I changed code to while loop from for loop. For loop code works fine but not this one. Only thing I added is extra method called printArray because without another method it keep saying your i already defined in method 'reverseNumbersWhile' when I define i for second while loop.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseNumbersWhile
{

  //Declare Variables
  public static final int num = 10;
  public static int nums[] = new int[num];

  public void reverseNumbersWhile(int num) 
  {
    //Create scanner and user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers : ");

    //Define i
    int i = 0;

    //For loop to fill the array
    while(i < nums.length) 
    {
      i++;
      nums[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
      } //end of reverseNumbersFor

  public void printArray(int num)
  {
    //Define var result and i
    String result = new String();
    int i = nums.length - 1;

    //for loop to print the array's elements reversed
    while (i >= 0 ) 
    {
      result += (nums[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("In reverse order : " + result);
  } //end of printArray 

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ReverseNumbersWhile sc = new ReverseNumbersWhile();
    sc.reverseNumbersWhile(num);
  } // end of main

} //end of public class
```

and here is my output. Scanner still works but seems other codes doesn't.

```
> run ReverseNumbersWhile
Enter 10 numbers :  [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at ReverseNumbersWhile.reverseNumbersWhile(ReverseNumbersWhile.java:34)
    at ReverseNumbersWhile.main(ReverseNumbersWhile.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
while(i < nums.length) 
    {
      i++;
      nums[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Imagine when `i = 9`, and it's still going to enter the loop, since `nums.length = 10`, and 9 < 10:

1. you'll first do `i++`, so `i = 10`
2. After that, `nums[i] = input.nextInt();`, but `i = 10`!

You can't do nums[10], since the array's index is only ranged in **0 - 9**.

To correct this, just postpone the i++ line.

```
while(i < nums.length) 
{
  nums[i] = input.nextInt();
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop code needs a simple modification.It should be something like this..

while(i < nums.length) {

```
    nums[i] = in.nextInt() ;

    i++ ;
```

}

pre incrementing is the cause for IndexOutOfBounds Exception.